# Less mixin to distinguish desktop / normal tablet / retina tablet

Tags: less, media-queries, tablet, retina-display

I am trying to use separate media queries for Desktop /  Normal tablets / Retina based tablets.
I have one set of visual design & icons for desktop, another set for tablets.

What is the best possible way to write a less mixin so that i can give one set of icons to desktop, another set to normal tablets and the 2X ones to retina based ones?

Right now, i am trying using the following snippet, but this one cant handle the normal tablet query. The less than, greater than symbol cant be used in media queries, else it would have been easy to write one mixin for device-pixel-ratio: 2 and another for device-pixel-ratio < 2  .

I tried with min-device-pixel-ratio:1 , but then, that gets applied to the desktop as well.
I need a query which can uniquely identify the normal tablets excluding the retina ones & desktop.
Is it correct to write like this for normal tablets? Putting a breakpoint just under 2 so that 2 and above will take the retina based query and 1.9 and below takes the normal tablet. But then, this query is applicable to desktops as well?

```
@media
      only screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9),
      only screen and (   max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9),
      only screen and (     -o-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9),
      only screen and (        max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.9),

      {
```

Query that i have now.

```
    .retina-image(@file-1x, @file-2x, @width-1x, @height-1x) {  
         background-image:~"url('@{imgPath}/@{file-1x}')";  
         width:@width-1x;
         height: @height-1x;      

  @media
  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
  only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
  only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) 
  {     
      background-image:~"url('@{imgPath}/@{file-2x}')"; 
      background-size: @width-1x, @height-1x;       

  }
}
```

Any pointers will be of great help!
TIA

Comment: see: https://github.com/imulus/retinajs

Comment: Thanks Bass... I just wanted to know whether its possible to do it with just media queries.Ive heard about Retina JS !.Thanks a lot for the reply though..